# Generar diagrama de clases y entidad relación a partir de código

Tags: java, eclipse

Debo documentar para mi proyecto final el modelo de objetos de mi aplicación así como el modelo entidad relación.

¿Existe algún plugin de eclipse o programa independiente que pueda hacer el modelo de objetos a partir de mis clases? Probé a instalar ObjectAid 1.2.4 que funcionaba con JDK17 y al crearlo no me dejaba :_(
¿Podría generar también el modelo entidad relación?

Comment: Los IDE de Jetbrains lo permiten. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/generate-uml-diagram/ No sé si es exclusivo de la versión paga. De todos modos puedes obtenerlo gratis a partir de [Github para estudiantes](https://education.github.com/pack). Una captura de la plataforma virtual de tu universidad es suficiente si no cuentas con otras formas de verificarlo.